# Does a single missing symbol from a .so indicate a bad build or corruption?

Tags: c++, shared-libraries

I have some code that crashed and produced a core dump. The top of it looks like this (with names changed) when printed in GDB

```
#0  0x00007f66be37d428 in __GI_raise (sig=sig@entry=6) at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c:54
#1  0x00007f66be37f02a in __GI_abort () at abort.c:89
#2  0x00007f66be9b784d in __gnu_cxx::__verbose_terminate_handler() () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
#3  0x00007f66be9b56b6 in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
#4  0x00007f66be9b5701 in std::terminate() () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
#5  0x00007f66be9b5919 in __cxa_throw () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
#6  0x00007f66be9de14f in std::__throw_logic_error(char const*) () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
#7  0x00007f66bf9798e4 in ?? () from /path/to/my/libname.so
#8  0x00007f66bf979c69 in MyNamespace::MyClass::function_3() () from /path/to/my/libname.so
#9  0x00007f66bf86020a in MyNamespace::MyClass::function_2() () from /path/to/my/libname.so
#10 0x00007f66bf855c0f in MyNamespace::MyClass::function_1() () from /path/to/my/libname.so
```

The exception at row 6 was a

```
what():  basic_string::_M_construct null not valid
```

However - the element at row 7 lacks symbols - this has gotten me thinking that I am looking at a  corruption issue or that somehow this lib was built badly somehow. I can't explain why we have symbols all the way up until the point of failure.

Are there legitimate cases where a symbol would be omitted from a core dump while others are not?

This lib was built with CMake with `CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release` so there are no debug symbols - but AFAIK that should not prevent the symbols for the actual function names being generated and used (like the `libstdc++` symbols in the exception handling) - although admittedly one symbol is missing there as well

Comment: Did you build your library with the `-g` option for debug symbols?

Comment: @walnut Edited the question to answer - essentially no. But, still doesn't explain why one is missing when others are not. Is there another criterion for whether the symbol can be found in a backtrace?

Comment: I'd have to look at the code fragment that is causing the issue, but it appears that this is not missi9ng symbol, but an invalid constructor.  It appears that specifying null (or probably nullptr) in a constructor is causing the issue.

Comment: @walnut Maybe the question then that I am actually trying to ask is "when is a symbol exported/not exported in a library" - and I'm guessing at this level that optimisation flags may remove/modify what we are actually looking for.

Comment: @JonBelanger yes - the string is being constructed with a nullptr. The origin of the nullptr appears to be memory corruption with a data buffer being pointed the wrong way. But my question is more about the contents of the stack and the missing symbol rather than the bug itself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> However - the element at row 7 lacks symbols - this has gotten me thinking that I am looking at a corruption issue or that somehow this lib was built badly somehow.

Your guess is incorrect.

The library `libstdc++.so.6` is *fully* stripped (to save space). The only symbol info that remains is for the symbols that are *exported* from the library (the ones that form its API), while all the internal symbols are removed.

You can verify this with `nm /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6` and `nm -D /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6` -- the former should produce "no symbols", while the latter will list a lot of symbols.

Solution is simple: install `libstdc++6-dbg` package. Once you do, GDB should give you a stack (using the same `core` file) with no missing function names (and with file and line info to boot).